# Migrating to NuGet Automatic Package Restore

Tags: git, tfs, nuget

I am [migrating MSBuild-Integrated package restore to Automatic Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) which became available with v2.7 of NuGet. Steps are easy to follow but I am confused with part that mentions `.nuget/NuGet.Config`

If I create a new solution with few projects, Automatic Package Restore "just works" and there is no `.nuget` folder at the solution level at all...

1. So why does migration doc mention I need to leave it? It works if I remove it...
2. [I read in the docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) that one possible advantage of leaving it is that "*Using this approach, rather than cloaking the packages folder or otherwise ignoring it, allows NuGet to completely skip the call into Visual Studio to pend changes to the packages folder.*" Is that it? Is this a big advantage (as opposed to having a cleaner solution)?

NOTE:
I am using Git in TFS and not TVSVC.

Comment: the migrate docs also talks about 'Use the .nuget\NuGet.config file to disable source control integration, as explained on the NuGet Config Settings document under the "Source control integration" section.'

Comment: @Deepak Yes, but if you look at the other doc (under Package Restore Consent, NuGet 2.7+) it says use .gitignore. Hence my question....

Answer (score 1):

That NuGet.Config file is only for Team Foundation Server (TFS). If you are not using TFS, then you can safely remove it. To quote [Migrating MSBuild-Integrated solutions to use Automatic Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore):

> By default, the NuGet.Config file instructs NuGet to bypass adding
>   package binaries to source control. Automatic Package Restore will
>   honor this as long as you leave this file in place. Note that
>   NuGet.Config only has an effect when using Visual Studio to integrate
>   with Team Foundation Server (TFS).